# How to get standard deviation of multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

I want to get the standard deviation of specific columns in a dataframe and store those means in a list in R.

The specific variable names of the columns are stored in a vector. For those specific variables (depends on user input) I want to calculate the standard deviation and store those in a list, over which I can loop then to use it in another part of my code.

I tried as follows, e.g.:

```
specific_variables <- c("variable1", "variable2")  # can be of a different length depending on user input
data <- data.frame(...)  # this is a dataframe with multiple columns, of which "variable1" and "variable2" are both columns from
sd_list <- 0  # empty variable for storage purposes

# for loop over the variables
for (i in length(specific_variables)) {
  sd_list[i] <- sd(data$specific_variables[i], na.rm = TRUE)
}

print(sd_list)
```

I get an error.

Second attempt using colSds and sapply:

```
colSds(data[sapply(specific_variables, na.rm = TRUE)])
```

But the colSds function doesn't work (anymore?).

Ideally, I'd like to store those the standard deviations from certain column names into a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of @shghm I found a way:

sd_list <- as.list(unname(apply(data[specific_variables], 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE)))

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have a dataframe with two columns. The easiest way is to use `apply`:

```
frame<-data.frame(X=1:6,Y=rnorm(6))
sd_list<-apply(frame,2,sd)
```

the "2" in `apply` means: calculate sds for each column. A "1" would mean: calculate for each row.

There is no `colSds()` function, but `colMeans()` and `colSums()` do exist ...

Comment: Also: `apply` is way faster than a loop, especially for large dataframes

Comment: and what if you only want to get the sd from specified columns and not for all columns? As I've posted in my original question: specific_variables <- c("variable1", "variable2")  # can be of a different length depending on user input

Comment: If both variable 1 and 2 are part of a dataframe they _will_ have the same number of rows...
If variable 1 and 2 have different lenghts then you could store them in a list and use `lapply()`:

framelist<-list(X=1:10,Y=rnorm(6))

lapply(framelist,sd)

Comment: who said `apply` is faster than for-loop? `apply` IS NOT faster than a for-loop. It is for-loop under the hood. For loop written in R with alot of overhead checks

Comment: There is actually a function called `colSds()` just not in the base package, check `matrixStats::colSds()`. also since you are using a dataframe, use `sapply(df, sd)` etc

Comment: Oh, I was unaware of `matrixStats` ... Indeed I meant to say there is no `colSds()` in the base package...